# Unable to start up compojure server

Tags: clojure, jvm, leiningen, compojure

I just created a new web project using the command "lein new compojure project-name".  When I run the command "lein ring server" to start up the server, I get the error message below:

`Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Unable to open cgroup memory limit file /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.limit_in_bytes (No such file or directory)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: No reader function for tag object, compiling:(/private/var/folders/v7/_rjly6_d5d5gyyj03142c4rc0000gn/T/form-init7926237026861890942.clj:1:8267)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7386)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7317)
    at clojure.main$load_script.invokeStatic(main.clj:275)
    at clojure.main$init_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:277)
    at clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:277)
    at clojure.main$initialize.invokeStatic(main.clj:308)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:342)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:339)
    at clojure.main$main.invokeStatic(main.clj:421)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:384)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:383)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:156)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No reader function for tag object
    at clojure.lang.LispReader$CtorReader.readTagged(LispReader.java:1245)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader$CtorReader.invoke(LispReader.java:1228)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader$DispatchReader.invoke(LispReader.java:684)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.read(LispReader.java:263)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.read(LispReader.java:200)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.access$200(LispReader.java:40)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader$MetaReader.invoke(LispReader.java:800)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.read(LispReader.java:263)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.readDelimitedList(LispReader.java:1200)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader$MapReader.invoke(LispReader.java:1158)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.read(LispReader.java:263)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.read(LispReader.java:200)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.access$200(LispReader.java:40)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader$MetaReader.invoke(LispReader.java:792)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.read(LispReader.java:263)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.readDelimitedList(LispReader.java:1200)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader$VectorReader.invoke(LispReader.java:1150)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.read(LispReader.java:263)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.readDelimitedList(LispReader.java:1200)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader$MapReader.invoke(LispReader.java:1158)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.read(LispReader.java:263)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.read(LispReader.java:200)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.access$200(LispReader.java:40)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader$MetaReader.invoke(LispReader.java:800)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.read(LispReader.java:263)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.readDelimitedList(LispReader.java:1200)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader$MapReader.invoke(LispReader.java:1158)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.read(LispReader.java:263)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.readDelimitedList(LispReader.java:1200)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader$MapReader.invoke(LispReader.java:1158)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.read(LispReader.java:263)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.read(LispReader.java:200)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.access$200(LispReader.java:40)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader$MetaReader.invoke(LispReader.java:792)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.read(LispReader.java:263)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.readDelimitedList(LispReader.java:1200)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader$ListReader.invoke(LispReader.java:1049)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.read(LispReader.java:263)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.readDelimitedList(LispReader.java:1200)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader$ListReader.invoke(LispReader.java:1049)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.read(LispReader.java:263)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.readDelimitedList(LispReader.java:1200)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader$ListReader.invoke(LispReader.java:1049)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.read(LispReader.java:263)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.read(LispReader.java:196)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7374)
    ... 14 more
Subprocess failed`

Comment: Have you tried starting the repl and requiring your files to make sure they all compile.

Comment: After reading the comments in https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/2329, decided to downgrade leiningen to 2.7.1 for now using the command "lein upgrade 2.7.1"